# close button in bootstrap-modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal. On pressing close button, the value of the array is getting changed but it shouldn't.

controller.js

```
    $scope.open = function(){

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/view1.html',
        controller: 'controller2',
        resolve: {
            items: function(){
                return $scope.array;
            }
        }
    });
modalInstance.result.then(function (changed_array){
        $scope.array = changed_array;
    },function(){
        // no change
    });
};
```

code for second controller

```
    angular.module('storagewebApp').controller('controller2',function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
$scope.array = items;
$scope.ok = function(){
    $modalInstance.close($scope.array);
};
$scope.cancel = function(){
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

});

view2.html

```
     <div class="modal-header">

    <h4 class="modal-title">Set threshold</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group" align="left">
   <div> E:</div> <input type="text" ng-model="array[0]">
   <div> M:</div><input type="text" ng-model="array[1]">
    <div>T:</div><input type="text" ng-model="array[2]">
    <div>F: </div><input type="text" ng-model="array[3]">
   <div> I:</div><input type="text" ng-model="array[4]">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The values are changed via input box but on pressing close button values should not be sent to the first controller, but on clicking close button value of changed array is passed to first controller.

Comment: Values are changed even if you click close, because when you open the modal you are passing the reference of your array from the first controller, and in the modal controller you are still manipulating that reference. Try in the modal controller to use: $scope.array = angular.copy(items);

Comment: This code is working in chrome and firefox but in IE, it's not saving the value in scope variable i.e. in the input box , previous values are not coming and after changing the values in input boxes, these changes are not getting reflected in scope variable.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is a common AngularJS/JavaScript mistake. When you instantiate your modal controller you are passing a reference of your array. Then inside of your modal controller you manipulate that reference, even if you don't pass it back.

When you write:

```
$scope.array = items
```

What happends in memory is that *$scope.arra*y points to the same location as *items*. When you modify in any way *$scope.array*'s object you are modifying *items* also.

As a solution you need to deep copy your initial array into the new one, in this way creating a new object and reference. AngularJS has an inbuilt function that does this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

```
angular.copy
```

See this plunkr for example: http://plnkr.co/edit/W6EYUwQ1K1YAnfnJ2r4a?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new scope for the modal window. Like this:

```
var modalScope = angular.extend(
    $scope.$new(), {
        val1ToPassToModal: $scope.originalValue1,
        val2ToPassToModal: $scope.originalValue2,
    });

$modal.open({
    templateUrl: '…',
    controller: '…',
    scope: modalScope,
    resolve: {
        …
    }
});
```

Of course if you don't want to pass new values to the modal window, you can write just:

`scope: $scope.$new()`.